# Como determinar se um número é infinito usando JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Existe a possibilidade de verificar se determinado valor é um **número infinito** usando JavaScript?

Comment: A pergunta não bate com o título. Qual exatamente é a dúvida?

Comment: voce poderia verificar o tipo com typeof variavel se for infinity daí vc descobriu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fora o exemplo da outra resposta que ficou muito bom, você também pode fazer assim:

```
var n = ...; //Valor infinito ou não
var isInfinite = (!isNaN(n) && !isFinite(n));

console.log(isInfinite);
```

O `isNaN` é para evitar que acaso `!isFinite(n);` retorne `true` acaso receba um numero `NaN`

Poderia mover para uma função para facilitar:

```
function isInfinite(num) {
    return !isNaN(num) && !isFinite(num);
}
```

Ou

```
function isInfinite(num) {
     return num == Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY ||
            num == Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
}
```

O uso ficaria assim:

```
alert(isInfinite(numero));
```

Todavia eu li na primeira edição que você usou um numero assim: `100000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000`, na verdade isto não é infinito, isto seria um numero que excede o limite

Um simples teste:

```js
function checkNumberSizeValide(num) {
    return num <= Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
}

function isInfinite2(num) {
     return num == Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY ||
            num == Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
}

var valor = window.prompt("Digite um numero, pode ser inteiro ou quebrado, exemplo 1.0000002");

if (/^(\d+|\d+[.]\d+)$/.test(valor)) {
    valor = Number(valor);

    console.log("valor", valor);

    console.log("O numero é valido dentro do limite máximo:", checkNumberSizeValide(valor));
} else {
    alert("Digite um numero");
}
```

Comment: *+1*. Eu também tinha visto o número na primeira edição... até estava formulando isso na resposta, o que eu iria sugerir era o [`Number.isSafeInteger()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isSafeInteger) mas a tua solução também é boa. :)

Answer (score 7):

Você pode usar a função [`isFinite()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite):

```js
console.log(!isFinite(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)); // false
console.log(!isFinite(Infinity));                // true
```

Uma outra forma é comparar o valor com [`Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/POSITIVE_INFINITY) e [`Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/NEGATIVE_INFINITY):

```
if (numero == Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY || numero == Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY) {
    alert('Número infinito!');
} else {
    alert('Número finito!')
}
```

Comment: Só uma coisa, da maneira que descreveu parece que isFinite checa se é infinito, mas é o contrário, então teria que fazer algo como `!isFinite(number)`, concorda?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento `isFinite` retorna falso para `NaN`, se você usar `!isFinite` como um aliás para `isInfinite`, o valor `NaN` vai ser considerado infinito. A melhor escolha mesmo é efetuar os testes de `POSITIVE_INFINITY` e `NEGATIVE_INFINITY` na mão. Eu também não conselho usar `isFinite` porque ele aplica coerção, então ele aceita `null` como um valor finito. Melhor usar `Number.isInfinite`.

Comment: @GabrielKatakura até aonde sei `NaN` não é bem um numero, o correto seria a checagem de ambos `var isInfinite = (!isNaN(n) && !isFinite(n));`, concorda? ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sim, era isso que eu estava falando para ser feito ;)